# Windows netsh advfirewall rule while also using 3rd party firewall like Norton

Tags: firewall

So if I am using windows defender I can use the following to successfully block traffic on a port using shell:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=block80 protocol=TCP dir=out remoteport=80 action=block
```

But I have a 3rd party firewall like Norton installed, I am still able to add the rule to windows firewall and the rule is there if I check but nothing happens. (The rule does not actually apply). 
How can I block a port like 80 for example through shell while there is a 3rd party software installed? Is there a way to override the 3rd party software?

Also, I need this to be done in a way from a c# program like command line or something.

Comment: Uninstall the 3rd party firewall, there is no need for a second firewall.

Comment: I am creating c# program. I cannot expect users to uninstall their antivirus.

Comment: You might add this new information to your question.